# Loop through array and insert items

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm working on a project where I read a VB.net solutions code files into a `List(Of File)` (File being a custom class) and then I loop through the `Code` (Code being a `List(Of String)`) property of each file.

What I want to do in that loop is add random code, but I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how to make this work correctly.

The problem is that code is inserted in places where I don't want it to be inserted.

I have tried a couple of different ways of doing this:

1. Simply looping through the Code property and adding lines if the conditions are right.
2. Adding another property: `Public Indices As List(Of Integer)`, then looping through that and inserting lines into the code property using the new properties values.
3. Adding another property: `Public InsertionLoopCode As List(Of String)`, assigning it the Code property and then looping through the new property and adding lines to the Code property

What the code looks like:

```vb
For Each Folder As Folder In Folders
    For Each File As File In Folder.Files
        For i = 0 To File.InsertionLoopCode.Count - 1
            If File.InsertionLoopCode(i).Contains(" Sub ") AndAlso Not File.InsertionLoopCode(i).Contains("Delegate") Then
                StartSub = True
            ElseIf File.InsertionLoopCode(i).Contains("End Sub") Then
                StartSub = False
            ElseIf StartSub = True AndAlso Not File.InsertionLoopCode(i).Contains(" Sub ") Then
                If i Mod Randomization.Random.Next(1, 5) = 0 Then
                    Dim RandomNumber As Integer = Random.Next(0, 2)

                    If RandomNumber = 0 Then
                        'File.Code.Insert(i, Insertion.InsertVariable(False))
                    ElseIf RandomNumber = 1 Then
                        InsertForLoop(File, i)
                    ElseIf RandomNumber = 2 Then

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

I don't think that it's the conditional statement, or at least not only that, as it works fine when I'm not inserting lines, but only doing msg boxes or writing to console.

EDIT: To make it more clear.
Before:

```
Module Main
    Dim WithEvents PlayerReader As New BackgroundWorker

    Sub Main()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Dim Player As New Player
    Dim Enemy(64) As Enemy
    Private Sub PlayerReader_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles PlayerReader.DoWork
        While True
            Player.GetInformation()
            Player.CheckState()

            For i = 0 To 64 - 1
                Enemy(i).GetInformation(Player, i)

                If Player.Health > 0 Then
                    If Player.Team <> Enemy(i).Team AndAlso Enemy(i).Health > 0 Then
                      Console.WriteLine(Enemy.Name)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

After:

```
Module Main
    Dim WithEvents PlayerReader As New BackgroundWorker
    *Dim awdasndwand As Integer = 29* 'Supposed to be Italic

    Sub Main()
        Console.ReadLine()
        **Dim yumngsef As String** 'Supposed to be Bold
    End Sub

    Dim Player As New Player
    Dim Enemy(64) As Enemy
    Private Sub PlayerReader_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles PlayerReader.DoWork
        While True
            Player.GetInformation()
            Player.CheckState()

            For i = 0 To 64 - 1
                Enemy(i).GetInformation(Player, i)

                If Player.Health > 0 Then
                    If Player.Team <> Enemy(i).Team AndAlso Enemy(i).Health > 0 Then
                      Console.WriteLine(Enemy.Name)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

The bold is supposed to be there, but the italic is not. Another thing is that if I only have a couple of files or I guess some specific files, it works just fine. As soon as I read the whole solution, it will insert variables in the wrong places.

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you want here. Can you give a (simple, short) example of what the code you read and change looks like before and after you've changed it? And preferably an example of what goes wrong?

Comment: I've made some changes to my original post, please have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the down votes came because the question was unclear. You clearly made a lot of effort to explain your problem, but much of what you describe are properties of a custom class you didn't share. Try answering (or at least reading and seeing if you understand) some other people's questions and it should give you a better grasp on when a question is or is not clearly communicated.

Anyway, even though I think your problem stems from code we can't actually see, I have a hunch on what's causing it. Your before and after suggests that when you reach the segment of code you posted, `StartSub` is already `True`. This is probably due to the scope of the variable; likely the first `File` is processed correctly, but since `StartSub` is declared outside of your `For` loop, it isn't reinitialized for each new `File`. Your code *should* set `StartSub` to `False` when it encounters an `End Sub` line, but if the previous `File` had this line missing or mistyped, this could be throwing you off. See if adding `StartSub = False` just before `For i = 0...` fixes the problem.

Also note that if a line in any `File` has a trailing space after `End Sub`, you will get unexpected results, as your code will never test for "End Sub" because it will have already found " Sub " in the same line. If your custom class takes care of that, great. If not, changing your first `If` statement to `If File.InsertionLoopCode(i) Like "*Sub ?*"` will give you safer results, as it will ensure there is some type of text after the word "Sub".

And on a Meta note, you've probably realized that formatting code (bold/italic) won't work inside of text already formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my post. I saw no reason for posting the classes as they are not the problem and are not needed to solve it. I know this because, reading a projects code files works perfectly, I can without errors or warnings randomize every variable name, sub name/call, function name/call, etc. and build the solution.

Comment: That **StartSub** is already true when continuing to another file, should not be possible because as I mentioned the files are okay and I have checked that by using msg boxes and writing them to a console. However, after having tested your suggestion, it works! Thank you man. I really don't understand why this is happening though, if you feel like fixing that too, all you have to do is create a variable of the type "List(Of String), loop through a code file and add each line to the array variable. Then simply copy the code from my post and try it out.

Comment: About the endspace, you would normally be right, but as visual studio automatically deletes any whitespace after the end of a line, this is not a problem.

Comment: Glad it works. The thing about custom classes is, *you* may be sure they're working perfectly, but as objective outsiders, *we* aren't. You may be 100% right and your class is perfect, or you may have tested it under certain scenarios but didn't consider a possibility that is now the cause of your problem. I've seen both cases here in the last week alone. As for the trailing space, yes, the Visual Studio IDE takes care of that automatically, but since you are manipulating those files yourself, it's possible (again, from an outsider's view) that they could be introduced.